# While using UnstructuredImageLoader getting an error : cannot import name 'open_filename'

Tags: langchain

After installing pdfminer for UnstructuredImageLoader to load image url,  I am getting an error cannot import name open_filename from pdfminer.utils.
[image_loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM5CZ.png)

I imported pdfminer and also tried changing the python version still getting this error.